# Haproxy using Prometheus on k8s

Tags: prometheus, haproxy

I have an instance of haproxy running on our K8s cluster and am trying to enable Prometheus metrics and stats for additional use.
I am running Haproxy from a pod built using the following image `FROM haproxy:2.5.8-alpine`

I've read through a lot of the documentation trying to set this up and have my frontend stats set up as such

```
    frontend stats
      bind *:8404
      http-request use-service prometheus-exporter if { path /metrics }
      stats enable
      stats uri /stats
      stats refresh 10s
      stats admin if LOCALHOST
```

When I forward the port on my pod to 8404 and access it via `localhost:8404/stats` or `*/metrics` I get a static page with the text `Not Found` and a response of 404 from the server.

I am trying to see what I am doing wrong or if this requires further configuration.

I am also not using `http-use-htx` as a lot of documentation suggests
due to errors I was resolving similar to this

https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/docker-image-of-haproxy-latest-seems-doesnt-like-http-use-htx/7261/3

I am unsure if this is related, but items in my frontend defaultincoming load. Anything not defined here results in the same `Not Found` message. Do I need to add anything to `frontend stats` as well to get this to work?

Comment: So I think I figured this out, but am not sure as to why this is happening. Below this frontend stats block is a frontend defaultincoming block binded to *:80 that I added the information too and it works just fine. If there is any information I am missing that would be great

Answer (score 0):

I guess this was a problem with my network controller, after fixing a few things I was able to get this working